# Pulling data from a website (livebox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mirc

I have tried this using the page sources but in the page source. The div tag i want is absent.

```
<div class="city-banner autumn livebox globalEvents">
<div class="cloud-3 content">
    <div class="cloud-2">
        <div class="cloud-1">
            <div class="plane-left">
                <div class="plane-right">
                    <div class="city">
                        <div class="ship left-course">
                            <div class="yacht">
                                <div class="precipitation">
                                    <div class="lightning-1"></div>
                                    <div class="lightning-2"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

while going through the Developer tools in chrom is was able to find the div i needed and (after i paused in debugger) then i could find the text i needed aswell.

```
<div class="bubble" style="margin-left: 537px; margin-top: 63px;"><div class="bubble-inner"><div class="bubble-text"><a href="/profiles.php?XID=1869105" target="_blank">barradell12</a> attacked <a href="/profiles.php?XID=593432" target="_blank">ChaosViper</a></div></div><div class="bubble-tail"></div></div><div class="bubble" style="margin-left: 181px; margin-top: 113px;"><div class="bubble-inner"><div class="bubble-text"><a href="/profiles.php?XID=492053" target="_blank">Nahid7</a> attacked <a href="/profiles.php?XID=1814701" target="_blank">FHC</a></div></div><div class="bubble-tail"></div></div><div class="bubble" style="margin-left: 1183px; margin-top: 7px;"><div class="bubble-inner"><div class="bubble-text">lol</div></div><div class="bubble-tail"></div></div><div class="bubble" style="margin-left: 615px; margin-top: 8px; opacity: 0.684062276342339;"><div class="bubble-inner"><div class="bubble-text"><a href="/profiles.php?XID=1869105" target="_blank">barradell12</a> mugged <a href="/profiles.php?XID=593432" target="_blank">ChaosViper</a></div></div><div class="bubble-tail"></div></div><div class="bubble" style="margin-left: 283px; margin-top: 8px; opacity: 0.561107899969945;"><div class="bubble-inner"><div class="bubble-text">Someone mugged <a href="/profiles.php?XID=1774422" target="_blank">cheesejointsuk</a></div></div><div class="bubble-tail"></div></div><div class="bubble" style="display:none;"><div class="bubble-inner"><div class="bubble-text"><a href="/profiles.php?XID=732076" target="_blank">rexxcii</a> attacked <a href="/profiles.php?XID=1017193" target="_blank">black15</a></div></div><div class="bubble-tail"></div></div><div class="bubble" style="display:none;"><div class="bubble-inner"><div class="bubble-text">Someone hospitalized <a href="/profiles.php?XID=689007" target="_blank">TheWalrus</a></div></div><div class="bubble-tail"></div></div></div>
</div>
```

Now ideally i would like the text like "xxxx attacked xxxx", "xxxxx hospitalized xxxxxx" to be pulled into a text file if possible.
P.s. the bubbles only last for a few seconds then they dissapear and more appear. So id like them all

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring this out. Did you have a question?

Comment: Haha that comment :P

Comment: Simple question: How do i do this? Im stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to automate something for [Torn](http://www.torn.com/)?

The best and easiest way is to create some nice userscript with Javascript (maybe in combination with jQuery) and inject it in the page. This can be done with tools like [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for firefox and [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) for chrome.

For the "how" to get it, query the path in a timer.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    //Scan for popup
}, 1000);
```

On what the correct queries are; only one way to find out.

Comment: Yes thats what im trying to do. I have Tampermonkey, how do i go about this?

Comment: Use the development tools on the right moment to discover where it's placed? alternative you could rip the javascript from the website, to see what it does i guess.

Comment: where what is placed? sorry im new to this

Comment: The information you are trying to extract? once you know where it's placed, you know how to build your jQuery selector query and voila, you can do whatever you please with it.

Can't help more than this without knowing the whole website structure, scripts etc. but this is whats needed in general.